# PHP trim, $variable[0] still displays nothing

Tags: php, string, trim

Assigning data to a variable that has a lot of white space in the beginning, I then do a trim to remove it and want to echo the first character which should be @. However, the echo displays nothing.

```
$data = '        @ JWHS8282';

trim($data);

echo $data[0];
```

Comment: You can even go with  "echo substr(trim($data),0,1);" to get the first character to be printed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) doesn't accept a parameter by reference:

```
$data = trim($data);
```

It is defined as:

```
function trim( $input )
{
   ...
   return ...;
}
```

NOT

```
function trim( &$input )
{
   ...
}
```

Note that the docs mark the signature of trim as returning a string:

> string trim ( string $str [, string $charlist ] )

Comment: And for clarity to the poster...This means you need to assign the results of the `trim` call, as in `$data = trim($data);`.